# ZeroMQ High Water Mark Doesn't Work

Tags: zeromq

when I read the "Durable Subscribers and High-Water Marks" in zmq guide, it said  "The HWM causes ØMQ to drop messages it can't put onto the queue", but no messages lost when I ran the example. Hit ctrl+c to terminate the durasub.py and then continue it.

### the example from the zmq in python.Other languages are the same.

durasub.py

```
import zmq                                              
import time                                             

context = zmq.Context()                                 


subscriber = context.socket(zmq.SUB)                    
subscriber.setsockopt(zmq.IDENTITY, "Hello")            
subscriber.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, "")                
subscriber.connect("tcp://localhost:5565")              


sync = context.socket(zmq.PUSH)                         
sync.connect("tcp://localhost:5564")                    
sync.send("")                                           


while True:                                             
    data = subscriber.recv()                            
    print data                                          
    if data == "END":                                   
        break
```

---

durapub.py

```
import zmq                                        
import time                                       

context = zmq.Context()                           


sync = context.socket(zmq.PULL)                   
sync.bind("tcp://*:5564")                         

publisher = context.socket(zmq.PUB)               
publisher.bind("tcp://*:5565")                    

publisher.setsockopt(zmq.HWM, 2)                  

sync_request = sync.recv()                        

for n in xrange(10):                              
    msg = "Update %d" % n                         
    publisher.send(msg)                           
    time.sleep(1)                                 

publisher.send("END")
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The suggestion above is valid, but doesn't properly address the problem in this particular code.

The real problem here is that in `durapub.py` you call `publisher.setsockopt(zmq.HWM, 2)` AFTER calling `publisher.bind`. You should call `setsockopt` BEFORE `bind` or `connect`.

Please refer to [0MQ API documentation for setsockopt](http://api.zeromq.org/2-1%3azmq-setsockopt):

> Caution: All options, with the exception of ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, ZMQ_UNSUBSCRIBE and ZMQ_LINGER, only take effect for subsequent socket bind/connects.

Answer (score 0):

**2024 update:**

For the latest version of ZMQ (4.3.6+), you no longer have to set HWM before bind/connect call. Many options can now be set after bind/connect... [see documentation](https://libzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/zmq_setsockopt.html).

However, note you may still see ZMQ buffering more than HWM messages. The reason is that HWM only limits the **in memory message count**. ZMQ will send messages to a kernel buffer, and those messages apparently don't count towards the in-memory message count (though you still may see the program's memory usage rise). To limit the kernel buffer, you'll need to set SNDBUF/RCVBUF options. The minimum buffer on Linux is 2048 for SND and 256 for RCV; depending on the size of your messages this may mean even with minimum kernel buffering (probably not recommended) you could still get > HWM messages being buffered at a time.

While we can't guarantee a bound on buffered messages, I'd recommend something like this:

```
SNDBUF = average_message_size * desired_kernel_messages
SNDHWM = desired_hwm - desired_kernel_messages
```

Note that currently, unlike HWM, the **BUF options need to be set prior to connect/bind**.